# Need regex to replace all symbols surround by a letters or numbers only

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex to replace all symbols surround by a letters or numbers only. With a space, I'll be using C# to run the expression and I'm OK with the part just stuck on the regex part.

So after the replacement the following

1. *Type-01* would be *Type 01*
2. *01*)* would still be *01*)*
3. *-Category:Toys* would still be *-Category:Toys*
4. *White:Back* would be *White Black*

Current Expression

```
(?<=\w)[^a-zA-Z0-9Category:]+(?=\w)
```

Input string is

> -Category:Toys AND (Teddy Bear Type-01*) OR (Teddy Bear White:Black)

Required output

> -Category:Toys AND (Teddy Bear Type 01*) OR (Teddy Bear White Black)

But what I'm getting is

> -Category:Toys  AND  Teddy  Bear  Type  01  OR  Teddy  Bear  White:Black)

Not sure if I'm just missing some thing simple or just got the wrong end of the stick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put words into a character class. All characters there will be added to that class, the order doesn't matter.

I am not sure if it is sufficient for you, but for your example, this will work:

```
(?<=\w)[^a-zA-Z0-9*:()\s]+(?=\w)
```

and replace with a single space.

I would  make it also more Unicode style:

```
(?<=\w)[^\p{L}0-9*:()\s]+(?=\w)
```

Where `\p{L}` is a Unicode property for a letter in any language.

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?32f8s)

**Update:**

If you want to keep the colon if there is "Category" before you could do it like this

```
(?<=\w)(?:[^a-zA-Z0-9*()\s:]+|(?<!Category):)(?=\w)
```

See [it on Regexr](http://regexr.com?32f98)

I added the colon to the negated character class to say don't replace the colon. Then I added an alternative to say: replace the colon, but only if there is not "Category" before.

Comment: I need to keep Category:Toys but I would need to replace say Type:01 to be Type 01, I'll update the question

Answer (score 0):

For C#, you can use the Regex.Replace function.

```
string a = "Category:Toys AND (Teddy Bear Type-01*) OR (Teddy Bear White/Black)";
string s = string.Empty;
s = Regex.Replace(a, @"[^()*:A-Za-z0-9]", " ");
```

Comment: I think the OP knows how to run it, but doesn't know **what** to run. You should update your answer to provide the actual regular expression